# How can I save conversations in Messenger?

Tags: history, windows-live-messenger

I use Messenger on Mobile and on the computer. I want to save my conversations when I log in from the mobile or on the browser.

Is there any way to save the talks from the mobile? I use the S-H or Ultra messenger. I want to save the talks so that I can access them from my computer in another time.

And is there any way to see all Messenger logs conversations for all friends on Messenger?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following. 
1. Open your yahoo email. 
2.Open the settings. And the option Messenger.
3. The would be the field ''to save the history'', just check this and save the changes. 
Hope that will help.

Comment: Is this for Yahoo or Windows Live Messenger? The asker wants to know about Windows Live Messenger.

Comment: Sorry then, this is for yahoo.